# Talend studio disable autocommit

Tags: git, commit, talend

I see that Talend Studio does a commit every time I save a change.  This makes for a long, messy commit history.  How do you disable that?

Answer (score 1):

Received this from [Talend Community](https://clicktime.symantec.com/a/1/_hmef4QhSJK9t3E169by5TPaAt9AciXhxRBjij9lpRI=?d=tK9fryZjdjsCDSgAOMZ3QjxMX45e4jyGpF3oZqQNRqEcxwPzgtzCWR61DfjHC8CS0FEqX25samDlt0UzVpQXl7-ntcBw1YHY68leHA9KhhWKxHNBP8-l7ozO-tBTI4pKdaPwshRG9WBQEJLLru7QyJY8-vs-jf8jLv335izh0Y3hf_ilG5skOOiLbwIgIOUmLLrhDf19Z5EErzq_vtGQPNDCOSbvgTmfSHIh9q9KRVsaobeu_QjQUSPm-de0n8JzUdNFm5AX_5BUjTUF32_qme4GoBVMzM2c9cn4EOysVseyL1AqvvwYRrIRfN57TV8TpeKQpLgfFLrGEoOZ8ZS5gasLUzAegPAfkUe97NvwGnjBWulxVjArHDe7H-POACE4RkhGbKwrlEIK1v4Rhwu9YK9pueX6EHqBe8qVTbCLafSgUJ24aCb0TjiRbYilNq-_9902FHPqdglf4VfS7PzUce3leodmAs0jEOpgst-x6mOjjQ%3D%3D&u=https%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.talend.com%2Ft5%2FDesign-and-Development%2FDisable-git-autocommit-in-Talend-studio%2Fm-p%2F132396%23M82548)

> This need to be set at TAC as shown in the image attached. Change the
>   commit mode to manual.